# How to get something stuck to something else?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I try to get the apple picture to be on top on the white triangle when the apple is over the triangle and I press h. I'm stuck and don't know what to do. When I do hit h, nothing good or bad happens. I can move my rectangle around, but not pick up the picture. And I do not know how I will get the rectangle to leave the apple either. Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *


screenSize = (640,480)
surface = pygame.display.set_mode(screenSize)


running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 1
y = 1
a = random.randint(0,640)
b = random.randint(0,480)


while running:

    clock.tick(15)

    surface.fill((20,150,100))


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x += 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y -= 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y += 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_h:
                a == x and b == y
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x -= 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y -= 0
    line1 = pygame.draw.line(surface, (0,0,0), [100,100], [10,150], 4)
    line2 = pygame.draw.line(surface, (0,0,0), [100,100], [100,300], 4)
    line3 = pygame.draw.line(surface, (10, 20, 39), [100,100], [190,150] , 4)
    line4 = pygame.draw.line(surface, (0,0,0), [100,300], [10,350], 4)
    line5 = pygame.draw.line(surface, (0,0,0), [100,300], [190,350], 4)
    circle = pygame.draw.circle(surface, (0,0,0), [100,60], 40, 4)
    rect = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (150, 50, 0), [350, 250, 100, 100])
    linerect = pygame.draw.line(surface, (75,25,0), [350, 280], [450,280],3)
    rect2 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (200, 150, 0), [395,275,10,10])
    rect3 = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (75,25,0), [360,290,80,50],3)
    box = pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,255,255), [x,y,100,100])

    apple = pygame.image.load('apple1.bmp')
    surface.blit(apple,(a,b))

    pygame.display.flip()



pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I've not tested your code, but there is a line that looks odd to me. What do you think this line does `a == x and b == y`? That's testing that `a` equals `x` and `b` equals `y`. I doubt that's what you want. Do you just want to set `a` to `x` and `b` to `y`?

Answer (score 0):

One of your lines is rather odd looking to me:

```
a == x and b == y
```

This should be an error since this line is not used in an `if` or `elif` line. `==` can only be used in an if or Leif line since it ***compares*** two variables. So using the above line does not do anything except raising an error or doing nothing. Try changing that to:

```
a = x
b = y
```

You need the two sections seperate and not use any excess code (the extra = and `and`). To put the triangle under the apple, you need to make sure the apple is over the triangle. Use collision code to figure that out. To make it easier, if they are both sprites, use `if sprite_name.rectcollide()` to detect the collision.

To make the apple "stick" to the triangle, you need to make the center of the apple the center of the triangle. So try changing `a` to the x coordinate of the triangle and `b` to the y coordinate of the triangle. Use another variable that can enable this sticking like:

```
sticky = True
if sticky == True:
    a = x
    b = y
else: 
    pass
```

And how you change `sticky` to False is your idea...

Comment: Thanks for writing the fuller answer. I don't think that line will cause an error (it will just evaluate to True or False) but it certainly won't have the intended effect!